# How to use swift to implement the function of drawing on PDF with Apple Pencil？

Tags: ios, swift, pdf

I'm developing a APP about making notes on PDF, but I can't find any information about the IOS platform's drawing on PDF. I try to achieve the effect of drawing graphics through cashapelayer into PDF uiview, but it will be slower and slower in the process of rendering. I can't find a good way to solve this problem. It has been bothering me for a long time.